# Line Invisible on Continuous Update of End Coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm attempting to draw a line using React and D3. Lines are being drawn but it is not visible/not updating itself continuously as the mouse pointer is being dragged (changes the end point of line) with the button down. On the mouse-button-up it does appear as expected. Made many attempts to correct but no solution yet. Source code is given below. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

let x;
let y;
const point = { x, y };
const pairOfPoints = { start: point, stop: point };

export default function PointerDraw() {
  const [lineCoords, setLineCoords] = useState(pairOfPoints);
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);
  const [startingPoint, setStartingPoint] = useState(point);
  const isDrawingNow = useRef(false);

  function handleDownEvent(event) {
    isDrawingNow.current = true;
    const currentLocation = d3.pointer(event);
    setStartingPoint({ x: currentLocation[0], y: currentLocation[1] });
    const linesSvg = d3.select('.lines');

    linesSvg
      .append('line')
      .attr('x1', currentLocation[0])
      .attr('y1', currentLocation[1])
      .attr('x2', currentLocation[0])
      .attr('y2', currentLocation[1])
      .attr('id', 'lineInProgress');
  }

  function handleMoveEvent(event) {
    if (isDrawingNow.current) {
      const currentLocation = d3.pointer(event);
      setLineCoords({
        start: startingPoint,
        stop: {
          x: currentLocation[0],
          y: currentLocation[1],
        },
      });
    }
  }

  function handleUpEvent() {
    isDrawingNow.current = false; // stop drawing
    setLines([...lines, lineCoords]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const linesSvg = d3.select('.lines');

    linesSvg
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(lines)
      .join('line')
      .attr('x1', (d) => d.start.x)
      .attr('y1', (d) => d.start.y)
      .attr('x2', (d) => d.stop.x)
      .attr('y2', (d) => d.stop.y)
      .attr('id', '')
      .attr('stroke', 'blue')
      .attr('stroke-width', '3px');
  }, [lines]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const liveLine = d3.select('#lineInProgress');
    if (liveLine) {
      // this is the line being drawn
      liveLine
        .attr('x1', lineCoords.start.x)
        .attr('y1', lineCoords.start.y)
        .attr('x2', lineCoords.stop.x)
        .attr('y2', lineCoords.stop.y);
    }
  }, [lineCoords]);

  return (
    <g
      className="lines"
      onMouseDown={handleDownEvent}
      onMouseUp={handleUpEvent}
      onMouseMove={handleMoveEvent}
    >
      <rect x={1} y={1} width={800} height={600} fill="lightgrey" />
    </g>
  );
}
```

Above component is used by the code below:

```
import './App.css';
import PointerDraw from './PointerDraw';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Click and drag to draw</h1>
      <svg width="1920" height="1080">
        <PointerDraw />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the line is invisible is because you are not setting the style attributes of the liveLine element. By default, the line element has no fill or stroke, so it will not be visible on the screen. You need to set the stroke and stroke-width attributes to give the line some color and thickness.

For example:

```
liveLine
    .attr("x1", lineCoords.start.x)
    .attr("y1", lineCoords.start.y)
    .attr("x2", lineCoords.stop.x)
    .attr("y2", lineCoords.stop.y)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "3px");
```

Comment: Oops, inadvertent error! A big thank-you for taking time to resolve the issue and pointing it out.